# Quartz clustering in camel spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to achieve **"requests recovery**" in fail-over scenario in two different machine with their clock also sync.

My configuration as below:

**step 1: camel-context.xml**

I have defined the below route in camel-context.xml file.

```
<route id="quartz" trace="true">
  <from uri="quartz2://cluster/quartz?cron=0+0/2+++*+?&durableJob=true&stateful=true&recoverableJob=true">
<route>
```

**step 2: quartz.properties:**

I have enabled

```
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName =ClusteredScheduler
```

Currently I am running same camel application in two different instances in my local and clustering is working fine . But when I try to test the "requests recovery" I am getting below exception.

**Exception :**

```
[QuartzScheduler_ClusteredScheduler-camelContext-16308243724_ClusterManager] INFO org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - ClusterManager: detected 1 failed or restarted instances.
[QuartzScheduler_ClusteredScheduler-camelContext-16308243724_ClusterManager] INFO org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - ClusterManager: Scanning for instance "6308270818"'s failed in-progress jobs.
[QuartzScheduler_ClusteredScheduler-camelContext-16308243724_ClusterManager] INFO org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - ClusterManager: ......Scheduled 1 recoverable job(s) for recovery.
[ClusteredScheduler-camelContext_Worker-1] WARN org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob - Cannot find existing QuartzEndpoint with uri: quartz2://cluster/quartz?cron=0+0%2F2+*+*+*+%3F&durableJob=true&recoverableJob=true&stateful=true. Creating new endpoint instance.
[ClusteredScheduler-camelContext_Worker-1] ERROR org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob - Failed to execute CamelJob.
**org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: quartz2://cluster/quartz?cron=0+0%2F2+*+*+*+%3F&durableJob=true&recoverableJob=true&stateful=true due to: Trigger key cluster.quartz is already in used by Endpoint[quartz2://cluster/quartz?cron=0+0%2F2+*+*+*+%3F&durableJob=true&recoverableJob=true&stateful=true]**
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:545)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:558)
      at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob.lookupQuartzEndpoint(CamelJob.java:123)
      at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:49)
      at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
      at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trigger key cluster.quartz is already in used by Endpoint[quartz2://cluster/quartz?cron=0+0%2F2+*+*+*+%3F&durableJob=true&recoverableJob=true&stateful=true]
      at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint.ensureNoDupTriggerKey(QuartzEndpoint.java:272)
      at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint.addJobInScheduler(QuartzEndpoint.java:254)
      at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint.doStart(QuartzEndpoint.java:202)
      at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:2158)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1016)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:977)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:973)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:541)
      ... 5 more
```

After shutting down the instance1 which is currently excuting the job , instance 2 is trying to recover the job immediately but its failing to execute the job .It is picking the same job in next interval (which is fine).

***My requirement is active node immediately recover the failed job*.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can avoid the checking of ensureNoDupTriggerKey, if the recoverableJob is true.  I just created [a JIRA CAMEL-8076](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8076) for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Willem. When will I get the latest jar including these changes?

Comment: I already committed the patch into Apache Camel git repository today, you should be able to test it by using camel 2.14.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Hi Willem,I have tested with the above jar and exception is resolved but my bean processor is not getting called from qaurtz end point. I have posted the detail about my issue in below link</br>http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Quartz-clustering-in-camel-spring-DSL-JIRA-CAMEL-8076-tp5759589.html

Comment: Hi Willem,I have found the problem and made temporary fix in camelJob.java please check and do the needful.<br>http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Quartz-clustering-in-camel-spring-DSL-JIRA-CAMEL-8076-tc5759589.html

Comment: The patch is merged into Apache camel repository, please check out the latest snapshot for verification.

Comment: I am using 2.14.1-snapshot but it does not have the latest changes but 2.15-SNAPSHOT has. Can you pls do the latest build.

Comment: The camel 2.14.x daily build is back to normal, you should get the SNAPSHOT with the right patch now. BTW, we are heading to release Camel 2.14.1, please let me know if the SNAPSHOT works for you.